# Listar grupos local do windows com forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Boas users!

Estou tentando listar todos os grupos local do windows com o forms c#, mas não obtive sucesso.

quero listar os grupos e a partir daí selecionar e incluir na criação do usuário.

desde já agradeço.

Comment: Pode compartilhar o código que usou pra tentar listar? Ficará mais fácil ajudar! :)

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Na verdade não tenho Código montado ainda, eu estou criando um programinha para criação de usuários local do windows, e queria achar um jeito de listar os grupos existente no computador para a pessoa selecionar e quando criar, já colocar esse usuario nos grupos selecionado.

Comment: Se não tem o código, como disse no tópico que está tentando mas não obteve sucesso?

Comment: Na verdade eu fiz um codigo de criacao de usuarios, e queria um jeito de puxar os grupos jogar em uma checkedListBox e dar a opcao de selecionar e ja criar esse usuario nos grupos selecionados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para grupos locais talvez isto seja o suficiente:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry machine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",Computer");

if (machine.Children != null)
{
    var results = machine.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Where(r => r.SchemaClassName == "Group").OrderBy(r => r.Name);

    foreach (DirectoryEntry child in results)
        Debug.Print(child.Name);
}
```

Para algo mais abrangente, por exemplo todo o domínio:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

var results = srch.FindAll().Where(r => r.StructuralObjectClass == "group").OrderBy(r => r.Name);

// encontrar todos os resultados
foreach (var found in results)
    Debug.Print(found.Name);
```

---

Aplicação **prática** de ambos os códigos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Exemplo 1

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryEntry machine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",Computer");

            if (machine.Children != null)
            {
                var results = machine.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Where(r => r.SchemaClassName == "Group").OrderBy(r => r.Name);

                label1.Text = string.Format(@"{0:#,##0} grupos", results.Count());

                foreach (DirectoryEntry child in results)
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(child.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Exemplo 2

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
            PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

            var results = srch.FindAll().Where(r => r.StructuralObjectClass == "group").OrderBy(r => r.Name);

            label1.Text = string.Format(@"{0:#,##0} grupos", results.Count());

            // encontrar todos os resultados
            foreach (var found in results)
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(found.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa cara, blz!
esse segundo código eu consegui ter retorno com um MessageBox e ele me retornou varias coisas, o primeiro nao fiz funcionar, em casa vou olhar com calma. meu Muito obrigado! vc ja me deu uma luz.

Comment: Minha ideia é jogar em uma checkedListBox.

Comment: O 1º código seria o mais indicado. Mas qual o erro que lhe dá no 1º código?

Comment: na verdade eu não soube fazer ele retorna algo, eu não tenho experiencia.
Qual o Código que coloco aqui para postar o código?

Comment: Resposta editada com exemplos funcionais!

Comment: Show!  Agora funcionou aqui!
@João Martins

Comment: Perfeito! Marque a resposta como correta e dê um UP! :)